# Java program only outputting one line of code

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I'm having a problem with my java program for my class.  I have to create a program that prompts user for the path and name of a output file that will have lines of coefficients of a equation that my program will take, and calculate the solutions using the quadratic formula. So far I think everything is right except for my output file. Say I have a input file with 3 lines of coefficients, my program will show the solutions in the console stream, but will only show 1 line of solutions on my output file.

```
while (input.hasNext()) {

    a = input.nextInt();
    b = input.nextInt();
    c = input.nextInt();

    discriminant = Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c;
    ///There will be no solutions if discriminant<0
    if (discriminant < 0){
        System.out.println("There are no solutions.");
        output.println("There are no solutions.");
    }
    ///As with the above, if coefficent a = 0 no solutions
    else if (a == 0){
        System.out.println("There are no solutions.");
        output.println("There are no solutions.");
    }
    else if (discriminant == 0){
       solutionOne = (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
       if (b < 0) {
           System.out.printf("%3.0fx^2 %3.0fx + %3.0f, has one      solution:%5.3f%n",a,b,c,solutionOne);
           output.printf("%3.0fx^2 %3.0fx + %3.0f has one solution:%5.3f%n",a,b,c,solutionOne);
        }
       else{
           System.out.printf("%3.0fx^2 %3.0fx + %3.0f has one  solution:%5.3f%n",a,b,c,solutionOne);
           output.printf("%3.0fx^2 %3.0fx + %3.0f has one solution:%5.3f%n",a,b,c,solutionOne);
       }

    }
       else if(discriminant>0){
           solutionOne=(-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a);
           twoSolutions=(-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a);

           if(b<0){
               System.out.printf("%3.0fx^2 %3.0fx + %3.0f has two solutions: %5.3f %5.3f%n",a,b,c,solutionOne,twoSolutions);
               output.printf("%3.0fx^2 %3.0fx + %3.0f has two solutions:5.3f %5.3f%n",a,b,c,solutionOne,twoSolutions);
           }

           else{

           System.out.printf("%3.0fx^2 %3.0fx + %3.0f has two solutions:%5.3f %5.3f%n",a,b,c,solutionOne,twoSolutions);
           output.printf("%3.0fx^2 %3.0fx + %3.0f has two solutions: %5.3f%5.3f%n",a,b,c,solutionOne,twoSolutions);
           }

    }

    output.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

If I'm reading your brackets correctly, the issue is that you're calling

```
output.close();
```

at the end of each iteration of the loop. You need to call that *outside* of the loop, after you're done writing all of the output.